.NET uses the wrong SDK Version despite global.json file
Problem
I'm attempting to publish a .NET Core project. I have multiple versions of .NET installed, and I have a global.json file specifying that for this project I want to use .NET 8.0.3.
However the build still fails because it tries to use .NET 6 (which I also have installed on my system).
I have tried the troubleshooting available in this documentation.
What I'm Doing
I have the target architecture for my project set as net8.0 like this:
<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>

I am attempting to publish my project with the following commands:
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 8.0.303
dotnet --version // outputs 8.0.303
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained

The publish command throws the following error:

error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0. Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0.

Solutions Attempted

Checked PATH environment variables to ensure there isn't a hardcoded path to a specific .NET version
Ensured no Directory.build.props file exists up the file tree
Ensured no MSBuildSDKPath environment variable is set
These commands are being run in PowerShell, so Visual Studio is not a concern
Confirmed that the correct target architecture SDK is available (SDK is located in Program Files, not Program Files (x86))

Additional Requested Information
Output from running dotnet --info can be found here.
Output from running "c:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet" --list-sdks:
The term 'c:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
error or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
error try again.

Output from running "c:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet" --list-sdks
3.1.406 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.408 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.413 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.402 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.303 [c:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]


Yes, that is the document I linked when I said "I have tried the troubleshooting available in this documentation"

@mjwills Running from Powershell, which is being executed by a bamboo server. I'll check the hard-coded path references you're suggesting and get back to you.

Also, looking at how bamboo runs the powershell - it places the powershell content into a ps1 and executes that.

That's correct, I've been adding these commands to the build script in the bamboo server, running the build, and copying the output from the bamboo logs that result from the run.

I'll try specifying a full path, and when checking the path I printed the $env object within the build's execution, so presumably that would be the path that applies for my script's execution environment.

I'm also now trying to explore the possibility that someone has manually mucked around with the dotnet sdk files on the build server. People have tried to solve this problem in the past and given up - they may have tried something silly. Checking if the MsBuild executable is correct within the v8 sdk folder.

I tried an experiment: I temporarily removed the dotnet 6 sdk folder to see what the new error message would be. I received C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.303\Current\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(14,3): error MS B4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Commo n.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Sd ks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Looking in that file I see this line. Going to try to hunt down what defines MSBuildSDKsPath -- <Import Project="$(MSBuildSDKsPath)\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Common.targets" />

MSBuildSDKsPath is definitely pointing to the wrong place:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Sdks

Setting this just before publishing resolved the issue (it's covered in the troubleshooting documentation, I just missed it because I'm a dumb dumb) [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('MSBuildSDKsPath', $null)

Gotcha, so apparently MSBuildSDKPath was set. In future be sure to get Bamboo to tell you the state of the environment variables in the context of the build pipeline. Anyway - well done for solving it!
